# Representation for a curve of constant curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

In Prof Ted Shifrin's differential geometry book linked [here](https://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Eshifrin/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf), problem 22 on page 21 is about obtaining an integral representation for a curve $\boldsymbol{\alpha}(s)$ of constant torsion $c$ using the binormal vector $\boldsymbol{b}$ defined over an interval $[a,b]$. This is of the form

$$ \boldsymbol{\alpha}(t) = \frac{1}{c} \int_a^t \boldsymbol{b}(u) \times \boldsymbol{\dot{b}}(u)\ \mathrm{d}u,$$

with $t \in [a,b]$.

I am trying to obtain a similar representation for a curve of constant curvature. I think this should be possible, But I am not sure how to go about this problem? Any hints?? I apologise if this is something trivial and I am missing something simple.

Comment: But you're confusing the point here. You start with an arbitrary (smooth) vector function $Y$ of magnitude $1$ and construct $\alpha$. It turns out after the fact that $Y$ is (up to sign) the binormal. You're presumably asking if there's a similar way to get a curve of constant curvature by starting with a vector function of magnitude $1$. I will have to think about that.

Comment: I don't think there's a good answer other than this. Take any unit vector field $Y$ whose derivative has constant magnitude $c$. Then define $\alpha(t) = \int_a^t Y(u)\,du$. Not very interesting.

Comment: @TedShifrin  Thank you, Prof Shifrin. I understand your comments. It seemed to me that if there is an integral representation for a curve of constant torsion using its binormal vectors and derivative and also for the Bertrand curve using a linear combination of its tangent and binormal vector, I was wondering if there is one involving just the tangent vector or its derivatives for a curve of constant curvature.

Comment: The last suspicion is purely based on what I got for the Bertrand curve and a curve of constant torsion. I see the Bertrand curve, curve of constant curvature and curve of constant torsion as being part of one family with the latter two being extremes.